# Single tab is not stretching full on the tablayout

Tags: android

I have created a view pager with TabLayout. Now the issue is if I have 2 or more tabs then everything is fine. But if I am having only one tab then it is not covering the entire screen width.

Comment: Seems like all you need yo do is just play with layout_width set it to match_parent if there is only one tab

Comment: I did that, but that is also not helping.